# how can I do required filed validation in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

this code for required fields but it does not work. I want each filed have value otherwayes when click button any filed has no value res message says "required".

the code in aspx:

```
  <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div>  

       <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  



<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="txtName" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       <br />  
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  
       <br />  
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  


<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="txtMobile" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  
       <br />  
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  


<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  
       <br />



       <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />  
   </div> 
    </div>
</form>
```

---

Code in aspx.cs

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        register R = new register();

        R.name = txtName.Text.ToString();
        R.email = txtEmail.Text.ToString();
        R.mobile = txtMobile.Text.ToString();
        R.Password = txtPassword.Text.ToString();
        var context = new ValidationContext(R, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(R, context, results, true);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            foreach (var validationResult in results)
            {
                Response.Write(validationResult.ErrorMessage.ToString());
            }

            return;
        }
    }
```

---

in class i don not what to put...

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `validationgroup="info"` to all validators and button.

Comment: can u please post the message?

Comment: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping called jquery (case-insensitive).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred while executing the current web request. Please see the stack trace for more information about the error and where it occurs in your code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping called jquery (case-insensitive